# Update LiveData from GcmListenerService

Tags: android, android-room, android-architecture-components, android-livedata

I am doing with **Android Architecture Component**. My app uses `GcmListenerService` for receiving push notification. Each time I get a push notification, I call api to refresh data to update `MainScreen`(Store to db).

I have a problem when I update data from `GcmListenerService`, it is not obsered from the `MainScreen`(listen data from db). My codes below:

**GCMListenerService.kt**

```
    class GCMListenerService : GcmListenerService() {
         // ....
         @Inject lateinit var chatRepository: ChatRepository
         fun processNotification(dialogId: String) {
            val handler = Handler(Looper.getMainLooper())
            handler.post({
                // call api here
                chatRepository.updateDialog(dialogId)
            })
        }
    }
```

**MainScreen.kt**

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(), HasSupportFragmentInjector {

....
var listUnreadChatDialog: LiveData<List<ChatDialog>>? = null
fun initChatListener() {

        // Get unread chat dialog
        listUnreadChatDialog = chatRepository.getUnreadChatDialog()
        listUnreadChatDialog?.observe(this, android.arch.lifecycle.Observer {
            if (it != null && it?.isNotEmpty()) {
                val chatTab = bottom_bar.getTabWithId(R.id.tab_chat)
                chatTab?.setBadgeCount(it?.size)
            } else {
                val chatTab = bottom_bar.getTabWithId(R.id.tab_chat)
                chatTab?.removeBadge()
            }
        })
    }

}
```

**ChatRepository.kt**

```
class ChatRepository @Inject constructor(val chatDialogDao: ChatDialogDao){

      fun getUnreadChatDialog(): LiveData<List<ChatDialog>> {
        return chatDialogDao.findUnreadChatDialog()
    }
```

**ChatDialogDao.kt**

```
@Dao
interface ChatDialogDao {

    @Query("SELECT * FROM ChatDialog WHERE unreadMessagesCount > 0")
    fun findUnreadChatDialog(): LiveData<List<ChatDialog>>
}
```

If I don't wrap api insde Handler(with Looper) as the codes above, it will error.
I have 2 questions:

1. Why do I need to wrap api inside Handler with `Looper.getMainLooper()` when calling api
2. Why data does not updated when I process api inside `GcmListenerService` (if I call api inside other screens, it will automatically notify for `MainScreen` to update data)

Any answers are welcomed. Thanks!

Comment: `LiveData`? i dont see any `LiveData` here to be updated...

Comment: @pskink Live Data in MainScreen, It automatically update data when get data in MainScreen (store to database)

Comment: @pskink I have just updated my questions.

Comment: Yup, I call api with method `processNotification`  to update `listUnreadChatDialog`.

Comment: You can see my edit above. I use room to store db, all data I get from repository. `LiveData` here is from `DAO`

Comment: I insert data to room db successfully. But `LiveData` from `MainScreen` only automatically obsers changes from `Activity`, not from  `GCMListenerService`.

Comment: It 's quite long. I just edit the function `processNotification`. this method can insert/update to room db.

Answer (score 0):

When you receive data from gcm listener broadcast into class where you need and then call the api to refresh data

Comment: Yup. I worked around by using EventBus to broadcast event to update data. But I really don't know the reason. Thanks